# EU Travel at the end-of-year

Tags: germany, europe, france, covid-19

I'm a brazilian passport holder with a French residence permit living in France. We now have a nationwide lockdown here which will be lifted the 15th, being replaced by a curfew.

I would like to know whether it is possible to travel to other countries within the EU/Switzerland during the Christmas holidays at the end of the year. The French government made some exceptions on the curfew for the special days. Is there any quarantine imposed?

I am mostly interested in Germany, but to make this question also useful for other community users I would also like to ask the situation on Austria, Italy and Switzerland.

Comment: I used 'opinion based' as the reason for my close vote since we don't have a 'no crystal ball available' reason. Sorry, but it is completely impossible for anyone to tell which rules and regulations will be in effect four weeks from now. Germany, Austria and Italy are currently de facto closed for tourism.

Comment: I'm sorry. In France these rules are already available. I thought they would be also available in other countries.

Comment: https://reopen.europa.eu/en was created for that. Currently, both Italy and Austria allow travel for any purpose if you reside in France and can present a recent PCR test. Germany is more restrictive, with hotels apparently forbidden to offer accommodation for non-essential travel until at least December 20. I don't know how often the German government revises these rules or whether it hinted at its plans for the Christmas period but someone following German news more closely should be able to write a good answer.

Comment: So the [Foreign ministry states](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/coronavirus/2317268) that “It is expected that these restrictions will be in place until at least early January 2021.” Maybe that answers your question? Generally speaking, Germany has been quicker to impose restrictions than its neighbours (and with good reason as they have much better outcomes to show for it) so I wouldn't count on this trip. Note that technically many of the rules are set at the provincial or local level and might therefore diverge again at some point.

Comment: @Relaxed Austrian hotels are also not allowed to offer accomodation to tourists and there is a 24h curfew. Leaving your place of residency is only allowed for most essential purposes. Both provisions are in effect until December 6th.You are not necessarily prevented from entering Austria, but staying there as a tourist is in practice impossible. In Italy, the situation is different from province to provice, but also there, accomodation restrictions, curfews and even internal travel restrictions are in effect.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Useful info, thanks. What's a 24h curfew? A curfew after midnight? A stay-at-home order?

Comment: @Relaxed I ment an 'all day' (not time limited) curfew. You are not allowed to leave your home unless you have an essential reason to do so (buying groceries, going to work, going to the doctor etc.).The restrictions were initially in effect until Nov 30th, but have now been extended until Dec 6th and may of course be extended again if it is seen necessary.

Comment: Generally Germany reviews these restrictions every 2 weeks.

Comment: @embedded_dev "_In France these rules are already available_". No, not quite. They're plans, if everything goes well, this has been repeated numerous times. I'm afraid there is absolutely no certainty that any of that will come to fruition, and past experience shows that it can change pretty quickly. We will see the result of the last relaxing of the rules in a couple of weeks.

Comment: German hotels are not allowed to accomodate non-business travellers until 20th December. Some federal states plan to allow family-visitors in hotels on Christmas, but I both doubt you would fall under this definition, as well as that the "non-business"-ban wont be prolonged. Also, most cultural venues in Germany are closed right now, so all you could do would be wandering the streets.

Comment: @jcaron No one said the rules were immutable. They are *forecasts*. I believe *nothing* the government ever says can be taken for granted. But we plan based in what is known and planned, even though it can change at any minute.

Comment: @Erik Hotels don't concern me, neither do cultural venues, since I won't be interested in any of them. My doubts lie more on the entry/exit regulations.

Comment: @embedded_dev Entry/exit regulations and especially movement about the country do depend somewhat on the purpose of the trip. We assumed this was a touristic trip (hence the comments) but perhaps it would be worth clarifying that in the question.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo OK, thanks, that's clear. I was confused by the word “curfew”, which tends to suggest restrictions limited in time.

Comment: It is a touristic trip but It's censed to be a camper van trip only to natural spots. Me and my friends want to avoid visiting crowded places/getting in contact with people.

Answer (score 1):

**Entry** to Germany from EU countries for any reason is [permitted as of now](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/EN/topics/civil-protection/coronavirus/travel-restrictions-border-control/travel-restriction-border-control-list.html#f13919566) (December 2nd 2020):

> No pandemic-related travel restrictions apply to travellers entering Germany from another member state of the European Union or from the United Kingdom, Switzerland, Liechtenstein, Norway or Iceland. The current travel restrictions apply to travellers entering from countries that do not belong to the EU and are not listed in the previous sentence.
>
> However, all travellers must follow the quarantine rules of the relevant federal state of Germany and the [digital registration procedure](https://www.einreiseanmeldung.de/#/) for registration upon entry.

As stated on the [website of the Auswärtiges Amt](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/coronavirus/2317268), you must fill out the online registration form before you enter Germany, and you must quarantine for 10 days. The quarantine can be ended earlier if you get a negative PCR test. This test must be taken **no earlier than** 5 days after arriving into Germany. The quarantine regulations are slightly different in the different federal states (Länder), so you should check the regulations of your own state.

**Hotels** in Germany are [closed for touristic travelers](https://www.adac.de/news/beherbergungsverbot-corona-hotspots/) until January 10th. Some states (Länder) plan to open hotels between December 23rd and January 1st for **family visits**, other states do not plan to do this. That [link](https://www.adac.de/news/beherbergungsverbot-corona-hotspots/) includes this information, but these openings are just plans, as they have not been implemented yet. The situation has been changing almost every week, so all the information in this answer might become obsolete soon.

Comment: It was already today announced by the German government that the partial lockdown will be extended beyond December 20th at least until January 10th.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo yes, I updated my answer. I did not expect another change so soon... I guess this answer is going to become obsolete quickly anyway...